# Javascript Next Sibling

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have an example fiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish:
https://jsfiddle.net/qscL4gjh/1/

The input box must be a "text" input (not "number") and only allow either a blank value or 8 numeric digits. I have that part working.

But I want to show an error block (underneath the input) if the user enters a key value that does not meet the requirements - and for some reason **I cannot get javascript to recognize the error block**. I want the error block to appear for 3 seconds and fade out.

```js
function validateObj(obj, evt) {
   var key = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
   var b = (!(key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) && obj.value.length < 9);
   if (!b) {
    var a = obj.getAttribute("data-errorid");
    console.log("Error Block Id: " + a);
    
    
     var $err = document.querySelector(a) || obj.nextElementSibling;
     
     if ($err.length) {
       console.log("Found error note");
       $err.style.visibility = "visible";
       $err.style.opacity = "1";
       $err.style.transition = "3s";
       $err.style.opacity = "0";
     }
     else {
       console.error("Could not find error block");
     }
   }
   return b;
 }
```

```html
<label>Test 1</label>
<input type="text" id="num" value="" onkeypress="return validateObj(this, event)" data-errorid="#error_note1" value=""/>
<div id="error_note1" class="error_note">
  Must be empty or 8 numeric digits
</div>

<br><br>

<label>Test2</label>
<input type="text" id="num" value="" onkeypress="return validateObj(this, event)" data-errorid="#error_note2" value=""/>
<div id="error_note2" class="error_note">
  Must be empty or 8 numeric digits
</div>
```

Comment: Is the error code during the time user types? or after leaving the input by focusing elsewhere?

Comment: Its onkeypress - so as the user types

Comment: The problem is that elements don't have a `length` property, so `if ($err.length)`1 will never be true. You're using `querySelector` or `nextElementSibling`, not `querySelectorAll`. They return an element (or `null`), not a list. Just `if ($err)` (and `nextElementSibling` should be all you need, you don't need the `data-*` attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below:

- Everything is wrapped in `<form id='UI'>` and is referenced via `.forms` property.

  ```
  const UI = document.forms.UI;
  ```
- Do not use inline attribute events, [inline event handlers are garbage.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) Use onevent properties or `.addEventListener()`. If you have multiple `<input>`s, register events on an ancestor tag like `<form>`, `<body>`, `document`, or `window`. Read about [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

  ```
  onkeypress="return validateObj(this, event)" //
  ```

  `.addEventListener(event, event handler, capture)`

  ```
  UI.addEventListener('keydown', resetVal); //
  UI.addEventListener('keyup', valData, true); // 
  /* ☝ certain events require the capture phase instead of the bubbling phase
  (see previous link to "event") */
  ```

  OR onevent property

  ```
  UI.onkeydown = resetVal; // 
  UI.onkeyup = valData; //  
  /* "keyup" events actually fire on the capture phase that's why 
  .addEventListener() is recommended */
  ```
- To always refer to the `<input>` the user is currently typing into, use the `Event.target` property.

  ```
  const inp = e.target; // Refers >inp< as the <input> the user is typing into
  if (inp.matches('input')) {... // Delegate event to >inp< only
  ```
- `.value` of the `<input>` which is a String is being validated vs. the `[pattern]` attribute of the `<input>` which is RegExp.

  ```
  <input id='test1' pattern='\d{8}'>
  ```

  ```
  const data = inp.value;
  const error = inp.nextElementSibling;
  const pattern = inp.pattern;
  const rgx = new RegExp(pattern, 'gm');
  const match = rgx.test(data);
  ```
- All styles are by class via `.classList` property.

  ```
  if (!match) {
    inp.classList.add('red');
    error.classList.add('flash');
  } else {
    inp.classList.remove('red');
    error.classList.remove('flash');
  }
  ```

This example will accommodate virtually an unlimited number of `<input>` (static and dynamic) and with minor modifications can also accept from `<textarea>` as well or `contenteditable` tags (`[data-pattern]` attribute and `.textContent` and `.dataset` properties).
**Note:** Flashing error messages isn't really good UX so I added the red text as a persistent reminder to the user that the text is still invalid.

```js
const UI = document.forms.UI;

UI.addEventListener('keydown', resetVal);
UI.addEventListener('keyup', valData, true);

function resetVal(e) {
  const inp = e.target;
  if (inp.matches('input')) {
    inp.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('flash');
    if (inp.value.length < 1) {
      inp.classList.remove('red');
    }
  }
};

function valData(e) {
  const inp = e.target;
  if (inp.matches('input') && inp.value.length > 0) {
    const data = inp.value;
    const error = inp.nextElementSibling;
    const pattern = inp.pattern;
    const rgx = new RegExp(pattern, 'gm');
    const match = rgx.test(data);
    if (!match) {
      inp.classList.add('red');
      error.classList.add('flash');
    } else {
      inp.classList.remove('red');
      error.classList.remove('flash');
    }
  }
};
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.error {
  display: block;
  width: 30ch;
  margin: 3px 0 6px 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.flash {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <label>Test 1 <input id="test1" pattern='\d{8}'>
<output class="error">
  Must have 8 numeric digits
</output></label>

  <label>Test 2 <input id="test2" pattern='^[a-zA-Z]+$'>
<output class="error">
  Must only have letters 
</output></label>

  <label>Test 3 <input id="test3" pattern='^[^\-\^\\\]()@#$%&*_+=~;:]+$'>
<output class="error">
  Cannot have special characters
</output></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function validateObj(obj, evt) {
var key = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
var b = !(key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) && obj.value.length < 9;
if (!b) {
    var a = obj.getAttribute("data-errorid");
    console.log("Error Block Id: " + a);
    var $err = document.querySelector(a) || obj.nextElementSibling;

    if ($err.length) {
      alert("Found error note");
      $err.style.visibility = "visibile";
      $err.style.opacity = "1";
      $err.style.transition = "3s";
      $err.style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
      document.querySelector(a).style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector(a).style.display = "none";
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
  return b;
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).